# Vue.js hyperlinks that change based on prop data

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink, onclick, vue-props

The homepage of my Vue project has multiple Bootstrap cards which each need to have a hyperlink button that shares the same base URL as the rest. The end of the URL needs to be the "name" property value of the prop that the card gets its information from. For example:

1st card - URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies" + "/bitcoin"

"bitcoin" should come from propName.name.

2nd card - URL = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies" + "/litecoin"

"litecoin" should come from propName.name.

And so on....

I've tried the following:

1. Using data() to return "baseURL" which has the value of the base URL, making "baseURL" the href value, then appending {{propName.name}} to the end.
2. Making a link button using an input tag which uses "onclick="window.location.href=... + {{propName.name}}"

Whatever I try to ammend "+ {{propName.name}}" to the URL, either the app fails to compile, or I get an error message stating that I can't use "+".

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your variables to `href` attribute:
`:href="baseURL + propName.name"`

I assume that `baseURL` is a property of `data()`.

Comment: It is a property of data(), & that worked. Thank you so much!